# how to convert Dataset Row type to Dataset String type

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 2.2 with java 8. I have a dataset in Rowtype and I want to used this dataset into ML model so I want to convert Dataset into Dataset when I used  Dataset into model it's shown below error.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dataset to Dataset

I fond below solution for scala but I want to do this into java.

```
df.map(row => row.mkString())
val strings = df.map(row => row.mkString()).collect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first convert Row dataset into list and then convert that list into String dataset. Try this

```
Dataset<Row> df= spark.read()... 
List<String> list = df.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
Dataset<String> df1 = session.createDataset(list, Encoders.STRING());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to read the dataset line by line, then you can use the iterator over the dataset:

```
     Dataset<Row>csv=session.read().format("csv").option("sep",",").option("inferSchema",true).option("escape, "\"").option("header", true).option("multiline",true).load(users/abc/....);

    for(Iterator<Row> iter = csv.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        String item = (iter.next()).toString();
        System.out.println(item.toString());    
    }
```